# Facebook Unity SDK - Handling Apprequests by code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I've been looking around the Unity SDK apprequest tutorial and I've been wondering whether it is possible to accept app requests by code.

Say for example that i wanted to accept apprequests by code in the application itself, so people won't have to go to the facebook page to accept requests. A part of my solution is:

**1.** To read the current requests given to the user & process the given data

**2.** Delete the current request and reward the sender if the request was accepted.

I know how to make some API calls and most of my current project uses a lot of them, but how would an API call look, if i wanted to an Apprequest?

I imagined something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> query = new Dictionary<string, string>();

query.Add("DELETE", "AppRequestIDHere");

FB.API(query, HTTPMethod.DELETE, someCallback)
```

Another problem i have is that i want to be able to check if the request sender's request was accepted by the receiver. Is there a graph available for that or an API call i can do in the situation?

Thanks in advance for any answers or suggestions, i would really appreciate any feedback and i apologize for the lack of code on my part.

I am fairly new in using the Graph API and i hardly know any HTTP.